# Name lookup of the local variable

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a question about name lookup in Groovy. Consider the following build script:

```
apply([plugin: 'java'])

def dependenciesClosure = {
    delegate.ext.name = "DelegateName"
    println name 
    println delegate.toString()
    project(':api')
}

dependenciesClosure();

dependencies(dependenciesClosure)
```

The `gradle check` command produces the output

```
webapp
project ':webapp'
DelegateName
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@397ef2
```

Taking that into account, nonlocal variable name lookup is performed on a delegate object first an, if the name's not found, performed on the global `project` object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Gradle uses a delegate first resolve strategy within configuration closures. In this case, the delegate is an instance of `DependencyHandler`. You can see what any given block delegates to by looking at the Gradle [DSL documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:dependencies(groovy.lang.Closure)).

**Edit:** To confirm your last point, yes, the build script itself delegates to an instance of `Project`.